# Blending motion for circles

Tags: java, 2d, processing, motion

How can I blend a moving circle's motion in an CPU efficient way which still allows for fairly accurate collision detection? I've tried stretching and rotating and ellipse, but it looks unnatural. I've tried drawing in between objects my sketch below. But the motion is still jagged between the frames,  and it's expensive to draw a lot of in between circles with transparency. Is there a better way to do this? For example, bridging the shapes or smoothing motion with a bezier transformation? Maybe holding the last two locations in an array and using the current and last two to draw a bezier curve and drawing a curved shape between the last location and current location with the data from all three points? How do you deal with fast motion where you need to avoid the "..." effect, but also need to use the current location for collision detection and so on?

```
int xprev;
int yprev;
int xcur;
int ycur;
float size = 10;
float scale;
int rotation = 0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw () {
  background(0);

  xcur= int(cos(radians(rotation))*200) + width/2;
  ycur = int(sin(radians(rotation))*200) + height/2;
  rotation = rotation + 5;

  //scale = dist(xcur, ycur, xprev, yprev)/2;
  //println(scale);


  drawEllipse();

  xprev = xcur;
  yprev = ycur;
}

void drawEllipse() {

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    noStroke(); 
    fill(255, i*20);
    ellipse(xprev+ (xcur - xprev) * i/10, yprev + (ycur - yprev) * i/10, size, size);
  }

  fill(255);
  ellipse(xcur, ycur, size, size);
}
```

Comment: Your animation looks fine on my computer. What do you mean when you say it's jagged?

Comment: I mean, it looks OK unless the motion becomes very fast, but it's quite processing expensive when dealing with lots of particles. I suppose I could wrap it in if statements, like  if (dist(xprev, yprev, xcur, ycur) > 5){ for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    noStroke(); 
    fill(255, i*20);
    ellipse(xprev+ (xcur - xprev) * i/10, yprev + (ycur - yprev) * i/10, size, size);
  }} But I wish I could find a more elegant solution that doesn't involve drawing a lot of circles.

Comment: I think also it doesn't look as good as it could because each segment of motion is still a linear blend, where it should be blended along a curve between the last 2 points and the current one. Although I know how to do that myself i guess, I'm more curious if anyone has other more elegant solutions. Seems pretty relevant for a lot of apps, for example Paint tool Sai does it brilliantly.

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "more elegant" solution? What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: Problem 1. Each tween between frames of motion is linear. Problem 2. Expensive CPU wise to draw a lot of shapes between frames. I'm just looking for alternative solutions, I just don't know what a better solution would be.

Comment: Part 1 I suppose I understand, although I'm still not sure why it's a problem. Part 2, nothing you're doing is particularly "inefficient" depending on how we're defining efficiency. Have you actually noticed a problem?

Comment: Well, mainly I'm trying to smooth fast motion in an app I'm working on. It's been a challenge maintaining a decent frame rate as it is. As it is I'm right on the edge of minimum acceptable performance. So I can't add too much that could slow it down. I'm curious how drawing applications are able to get such smooth brush motion.And I'm sure there are lot of other areas that should probably be optimized first but it's difficult to ask more complex questions on SO. lol.